# How did the Kazon fly Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the Star Trek: Voyager episode Season 2 Episode 26  "[Basics: Part 1](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Basics,_Part_I_(episode))", the Kazon subdue Voyager, board and proceed to touch ground on a planet. It seemed as though they immediately knew how to fly and operate everything about the ship. Even repair it.

For a species that's a bit more primitive and trying to steal new technology, how do they get all of this done? Is this explained?

[image]

Comment: How did the Kazon fly Voyager? Very well, thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Kazon seized Voyager with the help of Seska, who knew of Voyager's systems because she was one of the Maquis insurgents swept into the Delta quadrant and integrated into Voyager's crew in season 1.  Without Seska's detailed insider knowledge, disabling Voyager's auto-destruct capacity and seizing control of the vessel would not have been possible.

Comment: Thanks! I do suppose this seems like the most likely explanation. I knew about her previously being on Voyager, her involvement with Chakotay, I just hadn't realized she was able to impart so much knowledge on to the Kazon crew. Thanks!

Comment: A key detail about Seska is that she was Cardassian spy and so she would have had a keen interest in learning as much as she could about Federation starship technology.  She also had the intelligence training to take advantage of the unique situation she was in.

Comment: Great addition, thanks! That totally makes sense and now looking back at this series definitely helps clarify. Thanks!